# Filename getting changed in multipart request

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer

There is a file with Arabic name, and I am uploading it through postman. But, this name is changed into english characters once the API is hit. I want that the original Arabic filename should be retained. Please help!

Example: مالك is changed to E'DC.

P.S. I am using multer to handle multipart/form data, and API is developed in Node JS.

Comment: Did you try to set the language?
https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/

Comment: But, with default settings, an arabic text in request is coming as it is. It is only happening with the filename.

Comment: you can follow this link, https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5912.  it looks like postman has resolved the issue and they are suggesting this could be because server uses different encoding.